# In which folder should I install Composer on a shared linux server?

Tags: 8, composer

The "Questions that may already have your answer" do give various instructions on how to install Drush and/or Composer, but they don't address my question. I did come across this comment:

Q: drush - which folder for install on VPS / root server (newbie):
A: "You can install Drush in the folder of your choice. Preferably outside www-directory."

My question: I'm not sure if this is applicable to Composer as well? 
And if it is applicable to Composer as well, why do people give specific folders into which Composer must be installed into?

The reason for my concern into which folder I install Composer is because I want to run it without problems (in any case with as little as possible).

I'm listing the different options:

1. mdir bin, cd bin, install Composer in [~/bin] directory.
2. Install in /home/username/bin
3. Install in [~/bin] and move to /usr/local/bin
4. Install in the /usr/local/bin folder 
   That is a hidden folder, I can access it if I say "cd /usr/local/bin" in my terminal, but it doesn't show in the file manager of cpanel. How does that relate to /home/username/bin (or doesn't it)?
5. Install in the public_html folder (home/username/public_html)
6. One article says that Drupal is installed in the /var/www/drupal folder.
7. Another articles says that Drupal is installed in domains/websitename.com/htdocs/www

It seems to me that the [~/bin] directory is the preferred one?

Comment: I think the answer is here (I never tried): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20894518/how-do-i-install-composer-on-a-shared-hosting ~/bin/composer/composer.phar

Comment: Thank you - I checked it out (even more installation options but it didn't answer my question). They also mentioned "mkdir bin", as well as creating a directory where you want to install composer, i.e. /home/your_username/composer.

Comment: I did come across another article (https://test.joshmountain.com/blog/installing-laravel-and-composer-on-a-cpanel-server) where the writer replied to my answer as follows:

"Make sure you use `cd /bin` not `cd bin`, this will take you to the root directory before looking for the `bin` folder. You want to install Composer here so that it can be used by all cPanel users. "

I was not even aware that there actually is a /bin directory (because its hidden), but this seems to be the answer to my question

Comment: For what it's worth, `~` is just a shorthand for your home directory; so `~/bin` and `/home/you/bin` are one and the same (assuming your OS has home directories in `/home`).

Comment: Everything in `/home` is personal, whereas everything outside is system-wide. There may be situations where the web server hides parts of the directory tree from its clients for security reasons, in which case you might have to install binaries needed by the web server in oddball places like `/var/www`.

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR** My recommendation would be `/usr/local/bin`

It doesn't really matter as long as the directory is in the `PATH` of all users, and as long as it is not one of the locations which the OS wants full control over (those would be primarily `/usr/bin` and `/bin`).  For most situations, a reasonable location is `/usr/local/bin` because it should already be in the system's default `PATH` and it is intended precisely for this purpose -- local installations which are not part of the OS proper.

For Linux, you might want to refer to the [LHS entry](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#USRLOCALLOCALHIERARCHY); this standard codifies usage inherited from the original Unix.

If it's convenient for you, installing in `$HOME/bin` and then moving to a system-wide location is fine.  In fact, most `make install` etc facilities expect you to be doing something like this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install Composer on a shared linux server, do it in the /bin directory if you want it to be used by all cPanel users.

The /bin directory is existing but hidden, just type "cd /bin" (with the slash!) on your command line to get to it.

Comment: No, this is incorrect for most OSes.

Comment: Also, the directory is in no way hidden.